# How do i increase the integer field when comment is liked

Tags: python, django

I have a comment model, i want to increase an integer field when a comment is liked. How do i create a comment like for each comment made by user. I attached an image of what i tried, but still do not increase the integer field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTtGM.jpg)

```
class Comments (models.Model):
    comment_post = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    commented_image = models.ForeignKey('Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', null=True, blank=True)
    comment_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def comments(request, id):  
    post = get_object_or_404(Image,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.commented_image = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('site:comments', id=id)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    all_comments = Comments.objects.filter(
        author=request.user.id,
        commented_image=post,
    )
    images = Image.objects.filter(
        imageuploader_profile=request.user.id,
        image_caption=post,
    )
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'images': images,
    }
    return render(request,'comments.html', context)
```

Comment: Consider that a tracking likes solely by a counter field is pretty bad practice. As there is no information associated with each like, users can easily abuse the system by liking something more than once and you have no way to prevent it.  Usually one would use a new model to represent likes which has foreign key fields to a user and a comment

Comment: @Hymns, thank you. I was think of that also and i think it is the best way to go. Can you give me an hint(code) on how to accomplish this?

Comment: personally I haven't implemented this before, but you can find several resources about how to do this on stackoverflow and other sites.  There is also a django-likes package that handles this for you and can be added to an existing project

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to build a new endpoint that handles likes of the comment

```
/comment/{id}/like
```

include the logic of get get_or_404
once you get the object set it's like count to

```
comment.comment_likes +=1
```

you can also fo the unlike with the reversed logic

Comment: tired that but it is not increasing the comment. can you set up the complete code? i will attach an image of what i tried.

Comment: check the image i attached to my question.